# How does MIME relate to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-hosting, mime

Having uploaded my JavaScript, PHP and other relevant files to the web hosting server and tried to run  them on browser I had the following error:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:  "http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php".
```

It seems that the html and php files works fine but I assume there is a problem with the js files. I would immensely appreciate if anyone could explain what the actual problem is and how it can be resolved.

Best..

Comment: Are you using 000webhost? That error message seems to be specific to them.

Comment: @byteME  Don't forget the votes ;-) * * cough * *

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be using [000webhost](http://www.000webhost.com/), which I know, from experience, inserts a bit of HTML at the end of your HTML that triggers that specific warning in Google Chrome. You'll find this at the end of your page source:

```
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

The page at the URL has an empty response body, which suggests that it is simply a script that records analytics data. No actual JavaScript is returned.

## How to Fix the Problem

I was able to fix the problem by disabling that extra bit of HTML. Go to http://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php and fill the form out. The password is the same as the one that you use to connect to your server via FTP. Under "Manage analytics code," choose "Disable Code." Click Submit, and the warning message should go away the next time that you refresh your webpage.

If you don't know the FTP password for your domain, you can change it by [logging into your account](http://members.000webhost.com/), clicking "Go to CPanel" under the domain in question, and clicking "Change Account Password" under Main Menu.

Comment: I am using the 000webhost.. I disabled the analytics code and the error message has dissappeared.. But I still cannot view most of my web page.. Any idea? It works fine on my local machine..

Comment: @wecsam, how did you navigate to the analytics code management page?

Comment: @Pacerier I don't remember how I found the page. I just keep it saved in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Mime type means the type of file that you want your end data to produce. Here is a list of mime types:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#section_1

The server was saying: "do you want me to process a script? Or do you want me to display this code as html."

It is receiving a script and you want it to display an html. So, the server was confused.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the content type in your PHP:

```
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of this particular error, the PHP code (I assume) is actually spitting out JavaScript code. By default, Apache will send the contents of any PHP file as HTML, so the web browser receives the script but thinks it should be HTML. The browser is smart enough to "get over" the problem and interpret the script, but if you want to stop the error, make PHP let Apache know that it is returning JavaScript with this:

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
AddType text/javascript .js
```

in yout .htaccess / httpd.conf

Comment: That would only work if the file extension is `.js`, which is isn't.

Comment: @wecsam Haha, you are right. But shouldn't the extension be `.js`?

Comment: It's not in this case. Accessing the specific URL returns a blank page, so I suspect that it's really just a PHP script recording analytics data and then returning an empty response body but with the default MIME type.